# Control tint color in UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, tint

In most of my projects a UX designer will provide me a RGB color for an asset in iOS, but am having trouble providing what is needed for a tint color in a control.  To explain, since the tint ends up being a wide range of colors on the control, when the designer says this color, where does the given color end up being in the gradient?

And, do we have any control over the gradient range?

Comment: Even if it would be possible, it really sound tricky to me, i would create a new uisegment and use it in all my projects

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a custom gradient going, you might be better off having your designer give you some small PNGs of it and use `setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` to customize the appearance.

See the `UICatalog` sample project that comes with XCode.